# ¿Como configurar correctamente el LookAndFeel de JAVA?

Tags: java, java-swing

estoy teniendo un problema con el LookAndFeel de una app de escritorio desarrollada en JDeveloper, el tema es que al ejecutar la app desde el "Run", el LookAndFeel es "Nimbus", pero cuando hago el deploy se ejecuta con otro LookAndFeel.

¿Alguna recomendacion?

Calaro que nunca configure el LookAndFeel, es el predeterminado:

```
    public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(FrameInicio.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null,
                                                                            ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(FrameInicio.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null,
                                                                            ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(FrameInicio.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null,
                                                                            ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(FrameInicio.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null,
                                                                            ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new FrameInicio(0, "system").setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Pero al hacer el deploy, los botones son los cuadrados predeterminados.

**UPDATE:**

Tuve que añadir el siguiente código en el constructor:

```
        try {
        javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
    } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e) {
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    }
```

Comment: Que yo sepa en una aplicación de escritorio no hay deploys, eso es web, explicate mejor.

Comment: Cuando hago el Build > Deploy, que genera el .jar ejecutable